# most efficient way to move Array elements (pure C, no stdlib)?

Tags: arrays, c

so i am writing a program, and i want to move all elements in the array N places to the left. wether the first elements of the array get added to the end or deleted: i don't care, the last N elements need to be nulled out anyway. i could ofcourse just make a copy of that array.
like this:

```
int *buffer = [loads of elements, these get assigned dynamically];

int *tmpbuffer = buffer;

for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(buffer); i++) {
       buffer[i] = tmpbuffer[i + N];
}
```

(please ignore any pointer and sizeof mistakes, this is a  really quick sketch)

but i doubt that'll be efficient at all. this is an array with roughly 4400 elements. but that will be expanded to a LOT more elements later.

what am i trying to do?
see it like a terminal program, but slightly different. so there are a few text lines, and when there are more than N lines, the top most line will be deleted and there will be a new line at the bottom. even though this sounds like a 3d array (one array for all the vertical lines, and one for the text lines), it's not.

this is done without any external library's, because it's for a "kernel". (you might say that i am prob not skilled enough to do so, and you're definetly right, right now i only have VGA ouput and basic terminal, but when all lines are filled, it just erases the entire screen. i just like to learn this way: have an objective and chase it.)

i hope i provided enough info. if i didn't i'll try to provide it.

Comment: How does this statement  buffer[i + N] = tmpbuffer[i]; move elements of the array to the left?

Comment: You don't need to move the elements. Use a [ring buffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer).

Comment: @VladfromMoscow sorry, i edited it, it must be buffer[i] = tmpbuffer[i + 80]
@h

Comment: You can't beat memmove()

Answer (score 0):

Your approach

> ```
> // sizeof(buffer) is sizeof (apointer); I replaced that with (nelems - N)
> for (int i = 0; i < nelems - N; i++) {
>        buffer[i] = tmpbuffer[i + N];
> }
> ```

looks **very efficient** to me.

You may want to compare with a pure pointer-based approach, but I doubt there will be any difference

```
src = buffer + N;
dst = buffer;
for (int i = 0; i < nelems - N; i++) *dst++ = *src++;
```